# How to compute proximal mapping of function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

The proximal mapping is $$\text{prox}_{\eta, g}(w) = \arg\min_z \Big[\frac{1}{2\eta} ||z-w||_2^2 + g(z) \Big]$$

Now we want to consider the function $$g(w) = \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\lambda}{\alpha} \ln(1 + \alpha|w_j|)$$

What is the proximal mapping $\text{prox}_{\eta, g}(w)?$

I tried to plug in $g$, then get the derivative and equate it to zero, but eventually it involved something like $\frac{z_j-w_j}{\eta} + \frac{\lambda \cdot sign(z_j)}{1 + \alpha|z_j|} = 0$, which I'm not sure is correct and I'm not sure also how to proceed.

EDIT:

Full task is we want to solve $\min_w \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(w) + g(w)$ using proximal stochastic gradient, whose algorithm update step is $w^{(t)} = \text{prox}_{\eta, g}(w^{(t-1)} -\eta\nabla f_i(w))$ for a randomly chosen $i$.

Comment: How did this question arise? Is it an exercise or do you need it for something. Do you know for sure if there is a closed form for it?

Comment: @JensRenders It's an exercise, and yes, I believe there should be a closed form solution.  The actual task is to apply proximal stochastic gradient descent, and finding the proximal mapping is part of that.

Comment: @JensRenders Here's the exact words "Apply proximal stochastic gradient with this non-convex g. Show that when learning rate is small, then the proximal mapping is convex, and derive the closed form solution for proximal mapping." I'm not sure, maybe the "when learning rate is small" part is necessarily to finding a closed form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g$ is a separable sum, we can just focus on the 1D case. The general proximal mapping is then just the 1D proximal mapping applied on each component. In 1D we have
$$g(w) = \frac{\lambda}{\alpha}\ln(1+\alpha|w|)$$
Then the derivative of the function to be minimized is
$$\frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{1}{2\eta}(z-w)^2+\frac{\lambda}{\alpha}\ln(1+\alpha|z|)\right) = \frac{z-w}{\eta}+\frac{\lambda\operatorname{sign}(z)}{1+\alpha|z|}$$
similar to what you computed. So we need to solve
$$\frac{z-w}{\eta}+\frac{\lambda\operatorname{sign}(z)}{1+\alpha|z|} = \frac{z-w}{\eta}+\frac{\lambda}{\operatorname{sign}(z)+\alpha z} = 0$$
$$\iff \alpha z^2+(\operatorname{sign}(z)-\alpha w)z+(\lambda\eta-\operatorname{sign}(z)w) = 0$$
So using the quadratic formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
z &= \frac{1}{2\alpha}\left((\alpha w-\operatorname{sign}(z))\pm\sqrt{(\operatorname{sign}(z)-\alpha w)^2-4\alpha(\lambda\eta-\operatorname{sign}(z)w)}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\alpha}\left((\alpha w-\operatorname{sign}(z))\pm\sqrt{1+2\operatorname{sign}(z)\alpha w+\alpha^2w^2-4\alpha\lambda\eta}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$\operatorname{sign}(z)=\pm 1$$
From a computational point of view, this is a good solution. It gives 4 possible values for $z$, some of them might be non-real. By simply discarding the non-real solutions and filling in the rest in the function we are minimizing, we can see where it is the lowest.

You can [verify the solutions with wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28z-w%29%2Feta%2B%28lambda%20sign%28z%29%29%2F%281%2Balpha%20%7Cz%7C%29%3D0%2C%20solve%20for%20z)

Comment: Errata: The leading term should be $(\alpha w-{\rm sign}(z))$ rather than $(\alpha w+{\rm sign}(z))$

Comment: @greg correct, thanks!